# Angularjs two way binding is not working

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I’m trying to log variable which is the model of inputbox, but it says undefined, here is the coffeescript code.

```
.controller('setupCtrl',[
  '$scope'
  ($scope) ->
    $scope.userAge = [{age: ''}]
    console.log 2342424

    $scope.addAge = ->
      console.log($scope.age)
])
```

This is the HTML code

```
<form role="ageForm" data-ng-submit="addAge()" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required>
    </div>
    {{input}} butona koyup data-ng-click dene istersen
    <button type="submit" ng-click="addAge()">sdsadsdSave</button>
</form>
```

It says undefined for $scope.age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ng-model => userAge.age not age only

```
<form role="ageForm" data-ng-submit="addAge()" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="userAge.age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required>
    </div>
    {{input}} butona koyup data-ng-click dene istersen
    <button type="submit" ng-click="addAge()">sdsadsdSave</button>
</form>

$scope.addAge = ->
      console.log($scope.userAge.age)
```

Comment: thank you sylwester, it works, now i would like to know that how can i store this is in variable which is not defined in script?

Comment: i'm bit confused can you explain bit more please ?

Comment: sylwester suppose that i have an input
<input ng-model="x"> but x is not defined in $scope, how can i log it?

Comment: I belive is good practice to define you model in controller. But even if you didn't defined model in controller, everything should works please see here: http://jsbin.com/veyix/1/. another but is coffescript, it looks like it didn't worked for you.

Comment: Does it work with an object like that? I've use ng-model to define a string or int but never var.int